# Statement about semisimple quotient ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was doing some reading and I came across the following statement:

"Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be a two-sided ideal of $R$ such that $R/I$ is semisimple. Then $I$ is a finite intersection of maximal ideals $M \subset R$ such that $R/M$ is simple Artinian. Therefore, we may as well assume that $R/I$ is simple Artinian."

I have difficulties understanding this statement. Does anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

A semisimple ring $\prod_{i=1}^n R_i$ (each $R_i$ simple Artinian) has exactly $n$ maximal ideals, one for each coordinate. They are all of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n I_i$ where $I_j=\{0\}$ for one $j$ and $I_i=R_i$ for $i\neq j$.

Now, the maximal ideals of $R/I$ correspond exactly to the maximal ideals of $R$ containing $I$.  Therefore there are $n$ maximal ideals of $R$ containing $I$, and their intersection is $I$.

I do not know precisely what the context is, so I cannot comment on why it is acceptable to handle the case where $R/I$ is simple Artinian.  You would have to provide more background information.

Comment: This statement is the start of the solution of Exercise 3.20, as formulated on page 44 of the book "Exercises in Classical Ring Theory", by T.Y. Lam.

Comment: Exercise 3.20: Let $R$ be a ring and $I=\bigcap_{x \in X}I_x$, where $I_x$ is an ideal of $R$ for each $x \in X$. Prove that if $X$ is finite and every $R/I_x$ is semisimple, then $R/I$ is semisimple.

Comment: @J.Bosser OK, then in that case, you see that if $I$ is a finite intersection of ideals such that quotients by those ideals are semisimple. then the lemma above lets you rewrite the problem equivalently assuming the collection consists purely of ideals which create a simple artinian quotient. You'll still only have finitely many. It just lets you use the "apparently stronger" (although actually just equivalent) statement that you have a finite collection of ideals intersecting to $I$ which are maximal.